# I've gotten an oscilloscope! How do I take care of it?

Tags: oscilloscope, best-practice

I'm happy to say that I've gotten my first ever oscilloscope!! I want to make sure that I take good care of this equipment.

But I'm afraid that while I'm new to oscilloscopes, I'm new to taking care of them.

What are some DOs and DON'Ts of operating digital oscilloscopes, and good practices to keep them in running order?

Comment: @Bort What I get from that is don't connect ground to not-ground on a coupled supply. is that all?

Comment: I don't know if that is "all", but the question has already been asked.

Comment: Don't drop it out window or into water, be very careful with non-isolated supplies (every probe ground connects to earth), learn where the "default setup" button is. I don't there's really any other DO's and DON'Ts, most modern half-decent scopes are pretty hard to kill (although I did once blow the power supply of a Tektronix TDS744 by sitting it on top of a big honking mains transformer... still don't know why that was a problem though)